# logical AND and OR tags in Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber

How we can apply logical AND  and OR using tags in Cucumber?
I have applied below snippet

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty" },
features = { "features" },
glue = { "stepdefs" },
tags = { "@SmokeTestCases" })
```

but I want to apply logical AND and OR in tags 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically OR you have to use this:
For OR logic sapareted with comma(,)

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty" },
features = { "features" },
glue = { "stepdefs" },
tags = { "@SmokeTestCases,@SanityTestCases" })
```

Logically AND you have to use this:
For AND logic separated with quotes("")

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty" },
features = { "features" },
glue = { "stepdefs" },
tags = { "@SmokeTestCases","@SanityTestCases" })
```